# Can you please check my Cesaro means proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I wanted to prove the following:

if $x_n \to x$ then $y_n \to x$ where $$ y_n = {x_1 + \dots + x_n \over n}$$

Please can you tell me if my proof is correct? My proof is this:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Fix $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $|x_n - x| < {\varepsilon \over 2}$.

Then $\left |{1 \over n} \sum_{k=N+1}^{N + n} x_k - x \right | < {\varepsilon \over 2}$. Now let $M$ be such that ${|x_1 + \dots + x_N | \over M} < {\varepsilon \over 2}$ and $M > N$. Then 
$$ \left | \sum_{k=1}^M {x_k \over M} - x   \right | \le  \left | \sum_{k=1}^N {x_k \over M}   \right | +  \left | \sum_{k=N+1}^M {x_k \over |M-N|}  - x   \right | < \varepsilon $$
Here the proof is finished. But one can observe:

It is possible that $y_n$ converges even if $x_n$ doesn't: If $x_{2n} = 0$ and $x_{2n + 1} = 1$ then $x_n$ does not converge but $y_n \to {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Why is $\left | \sum_{k=N+1}^M {x_k \over |M-N|}  - x   \right |<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$?

Comment: @blue how do you obtain $$ \left | \sum_{k=1}^M {x_k \over M} - x   \right | \le  \left | \sum_{k=1}^N {x_k \over M}   \right | +  \left | \sum_{k=N+1}^M {x_k \over |M-N|}  - x   \right |?$$

Comment: See my proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440333/general-cesaro-lim-limits-n-to-infty-frac1-sum-limitsk-0n-lambda-k

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the proof is correct.

For your question, I think there are many way to sum up a divergent series like $-1+1-1-1\cdots$, which by some summation goes to $\frac{1}{2}$. The source you should consult as a reference is Stein's Fourier Analysis in his analysis book series. He discussed the convergence property of Caesaro means in detail. I do not have the book with me (I read it four years ago) and I do not recall the details. So that's all I can offer.

Comment: Thank you, also for a book recommendation!!