# How to presage Prove by Contrapositive, for Sequential Characterizations of Limit and Continuity? (Abbott pp 106 t4.2.3, 110 t4.3.2)

Tags: real-analysis, intuition

[Dafinguzman answered consummately](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/681082/85079) this question initially but it became too long. I  want to question for different beliefs.

**1.** $(ii) \implies (i)$ in both Theorems 4.12 and 4.19 posit sequences and then prove by contraposition. How to presage proof choice? Why not direct proof?

I still don't understand 'infinite number of hypotheses' in dafinguzman's answer.
Why not just posit one arbitrary sequence and work with that?

Example. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678680/85079) uses a direct proof after positing $\{x_n\}$ converges. But what sanctioned this? By dint of dafinguzman's answer, aren't there infinitely many convergent sequences, ergo infinite hypotheses? Isn't this the same issue?

Another example. Aren't there infinitely many [convergent subsequences with the same limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678715/85079)?
Doesn't this have 'infinite hypotheses' too and founder?

> [image]

(pp 3, 5 sur 14 https://math.la.asu.edu/~dajones/class/371/ch4.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short reason for the author not doing a direct proof probably is that he tried doing a direct proof, got stuck, then tried with the contrapositive and it immediately worked.

I don't think that there is a way to immediately tell when a direct proof or a proof by contraposition will be successful. You try with one method for a bit, see where it leads you (maybe you succeed), then try the other method and continue with the one that seems easier.

Why do I think that the contrapositive is easier in this case? Let's take a look at $(ii)$: for each sequence which converges to $c$ we have knowledge of what happens with the sequence of its images under $f$. That is, that these images converge to $f(c)$.

Note that there are infinitely many sequences converging to $c$.

The thing is that we can have "many" of those sequences such that their images converge to $f(c)$, without the function being continuous at $c$. Think for example of a function of $x$ whose values approach $f(c)$ whenever $x$ approaches $c$ through rational numbers, but not when $x$ approaches $c$ through irrational numbers. You really need *all sequences* which converge to $c$ to have this property for the conclusion to hold.

It wouldn't occur to me at first glance (or ever) how to use *all that information* at once to make an argument. Think about this.

On the other hand, the contrapositive asks to prove a simple existence fact which becomes easier to handle:

> There exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset \mathcal D$, $x_n\to c$ which doesn't imply $\{f(x_n)\}\to f(c).$

I say that this is easier to handle because you only have to construct *one* example which meets the criterion: a sequence which converges to $c$ but whose images do not have the limit $f(c)$. Constructing this specific example is more or less easy if you assume that the function is not continuous at $c$.

I'd like to add that there is rarely only one way to do things (or prove theorems). I don't want to give the impression that proving the contrapositive is the only way to prove 1; I only wanted to highlight why I think it is *an easy way* to do it. If you can create a direct proof, I'll be happy to take a look at it, it would be interesting for me.

Note. It is not a bad thing for an implication to have an *infinite number of hypotheses*. It's just that when all of those are required for the conclusion to hold, it is a bit difficult to construct a proof for it.

*Edit.* If you want to see examples of proofs by contrapositive, take a look at the great answer to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638756/when-to-use-the-contrapositive-to-prove-a-statment) Probably you won't get a way to $presage$ a proof by contrapositive, but it may give you some intuition.

*Second Edit.* Beware: a proof by contrapositive is not the same as a proof by contradiction. You can take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/262831/123170) which adresses the issue.