# Existence of probability measure, $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

**Problem statement:**

> Let $x_j$ be a sequence in $[0,1]$.  Consider  $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N f(x_j)\hspace 2cm (\star).$$  If ($\star$) exists for all $f\in C[0,1]$ then there is a positive Borel measure $\mu$ on [0,1] with $\mu([0,1])=1$ such that ($\star)=\int_{[0,1]} f d\mu$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$.  Furthermore, if $x_j\to x$ then ($\star$) exists for all $f$, and the above applies.  Which $\mu$ do we get?

**Note:**
There are other similar questions like this out there, but they don't ask you to show that $\mu([0,1])=1$ and/or ask about a subsequence instead of just a convergent subsequence.

**Attempt:**

Given that ($\star$) holds for all $f$ I can show that the the map that sends $f$ to ($\star$) is a positive linear functional.  Applying (one version) of the Riez Representation Theorem gives a measure $\mu$ as needed.  However, how do I know $\mu([0,1])=1$?

As for what happens when $x_j\to x$, I suspect since $f(x_j)\to f(x)$ and we are averaging that $(\star)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for $\mu([0,1])=1$, consider the constant function $f(x) = 1$ on $x\in [0,1]$.

For the second statement, if $f\in C[0,1]$ then $f(x_j) \rightarrow f(x)$.

In this case, the limit will converge to $f(x)$.

Thus, the measure is the Dirac measure at the point $x$.

Comment: Constant function that makes sense.  As for the other part, intuition says that knowing $f(x_j)\to f(x)$ and averaging gives $f(x)$ in the limit, but how to show this formally?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565288/can-you-please-check-my-cesaro-means-proof