# Convergence of arithmetic mean of first $n$ numbers of a convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given any convergent series $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$,consider a new sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, defined as
$$b_n = \frac{1}{n}(a_1 + a_2 + \dots+a_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k $$
for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ($b_n$ is the arithmetic mean of the first $n$ elements in $a_n$).

How do I proof that $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent with the same limit?

I have tried using the fact that $b_n \leqslant \text{sup}\{a_m\vert  m \geqslant n\}$ and $b_n \geqslant \text{inf}\{a_m\vert  m \geqslant n\}$, and subsequently taking limits and using that $L= \text{limsup}_{n \to \infty}a_n =\text{liminf}_{n \to \infty}a_n$. Is this sound?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565288/can-you-please-check-my-cesaro-means-proof and a bunch of other posts on "Cesaro means"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, it is bounded; let $A=\sup_n |a_n|$. Choose $N_1$ so that $|a_n-a|<\frac\varepsilon2$ for $n\geqslant N_1$, and $N\geqslant\frac{4N_1A}\varepsilon$. Then for $n\geqslant N_1$ we have
\begin{align}
|b_n - a| &= \left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k-a}n\right|\\
&\leqslant \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k-a|\\
&= \frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^{N_1}|a_k-a| + \frac1n\sum_{k=N_1+1}^n|a_k-a|\\
&\leqslant \frac{2N_1A}n + \frac{\varepsilon(n-N_1)}{2n}\\
&\leqslant \frac\varepsilon2 + \frac\varepsilon2\\
&=\varepsilon.
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Suppose $(a_n)$ converge to $\ell$.

$$\left|b_n-\ell\right|=\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k-\ell\right|=\frac{1}{n}\left|\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-\ell)\right|\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k-\ell|.$$

Using the the fact that $a_n\longrightarrow \ell$, you can easily conclude.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the theorem of Cesaro-Stolz, the discrete version of the l'Hopital rule. Set $c_n=1$, then since $a_n/c_n$ converges,
$$
\frac{a_1+a_2+…+a_n}{c_1+c_2+…+c_n}
$$ 
also converges, and has the same limit. The answer of Math1000 contains the standard proof (strategy) of that statement, which can also be found in wikipedia or linked there.

---

See also [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109069/stolz-ces%C3%A0ro-theorem) for some in-depth discussion of the theorem and its geoemtry.

Comment: Can it also be proven using the limsup/liminf argument I made?

Comment: No, I do not see why those statements should be true. The start of a converging sequence can be quite arbitrary. You can have, as example, 10000 terms of $a_n=2$ and the remaining infinity of terms equal 1, so that $b_{10001}>1.5$ and $\sup{n\ge 10001}a_n=1$.