# Prove or refute that $\{p^{1/p}\}_{p\text{ prime}}$ to be equidistributed in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, equidistribution

I've tried follow the **Example 3** (see minute 30'40" of the reference), where is required the related **Theorem** (stated at minute 21') combined with **Serre's formalism for** $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ (also explained in the video) from a  video in **YouTube**, from the official channel **matsciencechannel**, *An Introduction to Analytic Number Theory Lecture 07 Equidistribution* by **Ram Murty** to ask myself

> **Question.** Is the sequence $\{p^{1/p}\}$, as $p$ varies over all primes, **equidistributed** in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$?

I need to check if $$\frac{1}{\pi(N)}\sum_{p\leq N}e^{2\pi i m p^{1/p}}$$
**tends to zero** as $N\to\infty$, $\forall m\neq 0$, where we are denoting the **prime-counting function** by $\pi(x)$ and $p$ the sequence of **prime numbers** in increasing order.

I take the definition following the teacher in this video of the more high quality, to do the calculation $$L(s,\psi_m)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{p^{\frac{2\pi i m}{p}}}{p^s}\right)^{-1}=\zeta(s-\frac{2\pi i m}{p}).$$

Now I believe that it is required to say that one has a **pole** at $s=1+\frac{2\pi i m}{p}$ (notice that I believe that I have a sequence of poles, Murty's example only depends on $m$), and say that I can use the theorem to show that our sum $\rightarrow 0$ as $N\to\infty$, thus our sequence is equidistributed in the (compact) group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Can you explain if it is feasible such calculations or do it? I don't understand well if it is possible to  apply the theorem for my example, if you can state in details how one can use the theorem, then it is the best, and this example will be here as a reference. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: If you can see the video seach the channel **mathsciencechannel**, and after the label **videos** after few pages you find it.

Comment: Are you interested in the fractional part of $p^{1/p}$? This is not equidistributed, the fractional parts approach $0$.

Comment: For all $m \neq 0$ the limit is simply $e^{2 \pi i m} \neq 0$, so the answer is no. This can be easily proved using the fact that $p^{1/p} \to 1$.

Comment: No I only was interested to do an exercise and encourage to me to study more mathematics. Thanks, then has meaning the question? Thanks @AndréNicolas

Comment: Then you are welcome to add a detailed answer, because I try do this as first example. I don't understand well the theory, Then you can add an answer to say that isn't equidistributed. Very thanks much @Crostul

Comment: If some user want to explain what was my mistake following previous outline is welcome. Veryt hanks much all user by their patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the result of basic calculus in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565288/can-you-please-check-my-cesaro-means-proof), we can say
$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n e^{2 \pi i m p_k^{1/p_k}}= \lim_{p \to +\infty} e^{2 \pi i m p^{1/p}}$$
, where $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th prime number. Now, it is well known that $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}n^{1/n}=1$$
so that $$\lim_{p \to +\infty} e^{2 \pi i m p^{1/p}}=e^{2 \pi i m \cdot 1}=e^{2 \pi i m} = e^{\mbox{something}} \neq 0$$

Comment: Very thanks much for your calculations, and your reference.

Comment: I've accept your answer, both answers were very good. Thanks you and the other user.

Answer (score 3):

As $n$ goes to infinity, $n^{1/n}$ approaches $1$ from above. In particular the fractional part of $n^{1/n}$ approaches $0$, so the $p^{1/p}$ are not equidistributed modulo $1$

Comment: Very thanks much, I try undertand it. I hope more answers and after a day I accept an answer.