# Suppose that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty|a_k|<\infty$. Prove that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n ka_k\to 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

In case the sequence $|a_k|$ is non-decreasing then one can show that $ka_k\to 0$ and the result would follow but what if we dont have the monotonicity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty |a_k| < \varepsilon$.

If $n> N$ you have that
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n k |a_k| \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^N k |a_k|
+ \sum_{k=N+1}^n |a_k| < \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^N k|a_k| + \varepsilon.
$$
For $n\to +\infty$, the first summation at r.h.s. goes to $0$, hence
$$
\limsup_{n\to +\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^n k |a_k| \leq \varepsilon.
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_n=a_0+a_1+\ldots+a_n$. By [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts):

$$ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k a_k = A_n - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} A_k $$
and we know that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}A_n = L<+\infty$, since the absolute convergence of $\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n$ implies the conditional convergence. By [Cesàro theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565288/can-you-please-check-my-cesaro-means-proof) $\lim_{n\to +\infty}A_n=L$ implies $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{A_0+A_1+\ldots+A_{n-1}}{n}=L$, hence
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}k a_k = L-L = 0 $$
as wanted.